# jQuery cycle.lite plugin - how to give containing div a responsive height?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I style this page so that the height of the div containing the slideshow is the height of the images in the slideshow?

```
<html>
<style>
  img {width:100%;}
</style>

  <h1>Screenshots</h1>
  <div id="slide" style="position: relative;">
    <img src="https://multibit.org/images/en/screenshots/help-contents.png"  >
    <img src="https://multibit.org/images/en/screenshots/send.png"  >
  </div>
  <h1>Hidden text - how can I see it? This text is hidden under the slide show. </h1>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://multibit.org/jquery/plugins/cycle/jquery.cycle.lite.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#slide').cycle({
      delay:   -1000, 
    });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

[image]

At the moment the height of the div seems to be zero, so the text following is hidden underneath the slides.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**:

Your slide div's height is collapsing due to the absolute positioning of the images inside it, i.e. it's height is collapsing to zero.

You can overcome this issue by setting a min-height on the parent div:

```
#slide { min-height:352px; }
```

And here is a **[working FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/4wHkA/)**